# In C++, how to set a private variable in a derived class to an input value from a base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, input, ifstream, derived-class

I have a base class called Employee and a derived class called EmployeeMerit. The Employee class reads data from an input text file and sets variables ID, JobClass, Years, and ED to the input values.

The EmployeeMerit class should add an additional variable, called MeritRank, and set it to an additional input value (already contained in the file) from the input file. If MeritRank is set to 3, then salary should increase by $50. The variable salary is a protected member, which means it is used by both classes.

I have MeritRank in the EmployeeMerit class set as a private member. 
The Employee class has a readData function that sets variables according to the input file.

Like this:

```
void Employee::readData(ifstream& inf){
    inf >> ID >> Job_class >> Years >> Ed;
}
```

Using the MeritRank that is private in the EmployeeMerit class, how do I set that variable to the next input? This is what I was thinking. But, when I run the program, MeritRank does not change value. Please keep in mind that I cannot use friend classes or public variables.

```
void EmployeeMerit::addToSalary(ifstream& inf) {
    employee::readData(inf);     //Base class function
    inf >> MeritRank;     //MeritRank is supposed to be set to next input #
    if (MeritRank == 3) {
        sal = sal + 50.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your code, one line at a time. Examine the input stream and make sure that it is not in an error state as a result of a parsing failure, which would result in the `>>` operator failing. Learn how to use a debugger. Knowing how to use a debugger is a mandatory skill for every C++ developer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to read all of the data using one function call from client side. Make `readData` a `virtual` member function.

```
// Make it virtual in the declaration.
void Employee::readData(ifstream& inf){
    inf >> ID >> Job_class >> Years >> Ed;
}

// Overide the the derived class.
void EmployeeMerit::readData(ifstream& inf) {
    Employee::readData(inf);
    inf >> MeritRank;
    if (MeritRank == 3) {
        sal = sal + 50.0;
    }
}
```

Now clients can just call `readData` on an object. There won't be need to call `readData` first followed by a call to `addToSalary`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But, maybe I wasn't clear. sal is a protected variable. I'm concerned about MeritRank, which is not being modified by input values in the base class. Should I post more code?

Comment: @user7912, see the updated answer. This might work for you.

Comment: I am still getting the same outputs. Perhaps inf >> MeritRank is not reading any input :/